# Loading module from “https://app.herokuapp.com/assets/index.1ab7e925.js” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”)

Tags: html

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <base href="./">

    <title>PzCompare</title>
    <script type="module" crossorigin src="/assets/index.1ab7e925.js"></script>
    <link rel="modulepreload" type="text/javascript" href="/assets/vendor.d0b4acaa.js">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/index.e7475acf.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

All of the css and js files are not being loaded because of this error 'blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”)', no idea how to fix this, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you searched for this error message on any search sites? Because [when I do, I get a lot of results](https://www.google.com/search?q=blocked+because+of+a+disallowed+MIME+type+\(%E2%80%9Ctext%2Fhtml%E2%80%9D\))

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Module was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type ("text/html")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58173204/module-was-blocked-because-of-a-disallowed-mime-type-text-html)